# How say in Korean 'I learnt to ride a bike'?

Tags: spoken-korean, korean-to-english

Also 법 is a related word to its translation,how is it used?

Comment: Have you tried anything to find out what this means? Dictionaries,. online translations? Why do you think 법 is a related word? What do you think it means?

Comment: Papago said 'law'..and it also used the word in translation of almost all sentences related to 'how'to do an action

Comment: Do not use a machine translator when you study Korean. Read [this](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=62407) to get what 법 means. When you put this kind of question, you should mention both who will be the speaker and the listener and what the context is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'I learnt to ride a bike' literally means 나는 자전거 타는 것을 배웠어.

But to make it more natural, it should be 나는 자전거 타는 법을 배웠어 or 나는 어떻게 자전거 타는 건지 배웠어.

'verb + 하는 (방)법' = '어떻게 + verb + 하는 건지' = 'how to + verb' in English

'법' in this situation means 'way, method or rule' and it is similar with '방법'.

ex) 떡볶이 만드는 (방)법 = 어떻게 떡볶이를 만드는 건지

떡볶이 만드는 법을 배웠다. = 어떻게 떡볶이를 만드는 건지 배웠다. I learnt to cook 떡볶이. = I learnt how to cook 떡볶이.